# Nifi - Copy all the keys after transforming only one key

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, jolt

I want to copy all they keys in the json except one which i want to transform.
ex.

**Input JSON**

```
{
"ts": "20200420121222",
"name": "broker",
"city": "queensland",
"age": 21,
"gender": "male"
"characteristics": {
    "Card Id": "63247354",
    "Termination Plan": "paid"
   }
}
```

**Output JSON**

```
{
"ts": "20200420121222",
"name": "broker",
"city": "queensland",
"age": 21,
"gender": "male"
"characteristics": {
    "card_id": "63247354",        // change here
    "termination_plan": "paid"    // change here
   }
}
```

Is there any better way via which i can just change the following above keys and copy the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `"*": "&"` construct to include all other fields that have not yet been matched:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "characteristics": {
        "Card Id": "characteristics.card_id",
        "Termination Plan": "characteristics.termination_plan"
      },
      "*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you please help me with this.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61465241/how-to-provide-input-to-jolt-when-multiple-objects-are-given